# What's the difference between "id" and "pk" parameter with get_object_or_404

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django.

When I was learning how to use `get_object_or_404`, I noticed that some codes specify `id` as the argument of `get_object_or_404`, while others specify `pk`.

It seems that whether I specify `id` or `pk`, the result is the same.

```
    foo1 = get_object_or_404(FooModel, pk=1)  
    foo2 = get_object_or_404(FooModel, id=1)
    """
    FooModels table has some records that includes id is 1.
    When I access foo/1, foo1 and foo2 have the same values.
    """
```

How do you use these parameters differently?
Or if there is something fundamentally wrong with my thinking, please let me know.

Thanks.

---

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
class FooModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=20)
    body = models.CharField('body', max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('created_at', default=timezone.now)
```

**urls.py**

```
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path("foo/<int:id>", views.foo),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .models import FooModel
def foo(request, id)
    foo1 = get_object_or_404(FooModel, pk=id)  
    foo2 = get_object_or_404(FooModel, id=id)
    """
    FooModels table has some records that includes id is 1.
    When I access foo/1, foo1 and foo2 have the same values.
    """
```

---

```
$ python -m django --version
2.2.20

$ python --version
Python 3.7.9
```

Comment: `pk` is a special parameter for django that refers to the primary key field on the model. By default, django assigns `id` as the primary key field for a model, but if you manually assign another field as the primary key, then `pk` will refer to that field.

Comment: https://newbedev.com/django-queries-id-vs-pk

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr I could understand it well. Thanks for the clear answer!

Comment: @KiranChauhan Thanks for the informative article! I'll take that as a reference.